# Regex to extract string between the first and last occurrence of a character

Tags: java, regex

I am currently extracting a particular string from an Violation Exception Error message. The steps I did are as follows:

Input String format:
Duplicate entry **value** for key **key**

Regex Currently being used:

```
Duplicate entry '(.*)' for key '(.*)'
```

Obtained group 1: **value**

Format of the value ==> **some id**-**desired value**-**some id**

To extract the desired value, I currently use the first index and the last index of (-) and extract the string as follows:

```
error.substring(error.indexOf("-") + 1, error.lastIndexOf("-"));
```

Can the same be done by regex only?

Comment: Why the backslash before the asterisk in your regex?

Comment: @CaiusJard The asterisk wasnt displaying in the stackoverflow viewer so had to escape. But the escape character seems to show up in the final view. Will change it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with a one-liner using `String#replaceAll`:

```
String input = "some id-desired - d - d- value-some id";
String output = input.replaceAll("^.*?-(.*)-.*", "$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
desired - d - d- value
```

The pattern I used cautiously consumes everything up until the very first dash.  Then, it greedily consumes everything in between that first dash and the very last dash.  Weird sample data, but I wanted to show that the answer is robust to dashes occurring inside the desired data.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: just be aware that this will return the whole `input` if it does not have at least two dashes , maybe this is never happens or is desired....

Answer (score 0):

more or less straight forward

```
var pattern = Pattern.compile("-.*-");
var matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if (matcher.find())
    result = matcher.group();
```

-> find first occurrence of `-` followed by as many characters as possible, followed by a `-`. This also works if there are `-` inside of the *desired-value*.

Drawback, the dashes are included in the result, but can be easily discarded using `substring()`. This can be avoided using positive lookahead/lookbehind:

```
...compile("(?<=-).*(?=-)");
```